# Will IQueryable of EF work in sql server VIEW?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

If I create a view with a script like "Select * from tableA" and call the view via Entity Framework and I added a where clause/filter at the end will it return all of the records first before applying the filter or IQueryable work also in views? like "Select * from tableA where ...."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IQueryable` also works in TSQL Views. I have tested this using `Sql Profiler`

Comment: how do you declare this view in EF ?